# CakePHP htaccess modification to allow vBulletin

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, vbulletin

I'm looking to set-up a vBulletin install next to a CakePHP install. I was planning on just popping the the vB folder into webroot, but when accessing the folder in my browser, it loses the short URL (i.e. it goes from .com/community to .com/app/webroot/community)

Because of this I wanted to put the vB folder into the root of the directory, next to the app directory, so I can access it directly via .com/community - but the htaccess file is getting in the way, complaining that it can't find the community controller.

So my question is this - what edits do I need to make to the htaccess file for it to allow access to the /community folder directly.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule   ^(community).* - [NC,L]
```

This will allow direct access to the community folder which is in root directory. Accessing http://localhost/community would be possible after adding this rule.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm curious to know whether my solution above worked for you or not.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've not tried it yet - I'll give it a go when I get home from work this evening :)

Comment: Hi, I added it to the .htaccess in the root, and it works great. Thank you :)